# Excel accepts some characters whereas OpenXml has error

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

i have a string that i want to export on excel file with openxml component in C#. My text has '\u001f' character and openxml has error with this character. error text: "hexadecimal value 0x1f, is an invalid character".

i copy that test directly to excel and no problem and copy is success.

Does OpenXml have configs for solving this problem or How i can solve this problem.

thanks.

Comment: Show the code you tried please

Answer (score 1):

You need to write it using the format `_xHHHH_` where `H` represents a hexadecimal character. In your particular instance you need to set the value to `"_x001F_"`.

From the documentation for a [Cell Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue(v=office.15).aspx):

> The possible values for this element are defined by the ST_Xstring simple type (§22.9.2.19).

In turn, the `ST_Xstring` (taken from the [ECMA-376 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)) is documented as:

> 22.9.2.19 ST_Xstring (Escaped String)
>   String of characters with support for escaped invalid-XML characters.
>   For all characters which cannot be represented in XML as defined by the XML 1.0 specification, the characters
>   are escaped using the Unicode numerical character representation escape character format *xHHHH*, where H
>   represents a hexadecimal character in the character's value. [Example: The Unicode character 8 is not permitted
>   in an XML 1.0 document, so it must be escaped as *x0008*. end example]