# Apache POI jar is not able to write a special character in excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a special character in my string which I want to write in my excel file but poi jar replacing it with ?

Special character as below string:

[image]

Some site throw below unicode

1)

```
Unicode character          Oct  Dec Hex HTML
\x{F}   si shift in ctrl-o  017 15  0xF &#15;
```

2)

```
U+000F : <control-000F> (SHIFT IN [SI])
```

Example:

My string is as below

[image]

Excel showing output as :

```
PrincipalOffice~?DIRECTION
```

Code I am using is as something below:

```
String filename= "D:\\DataFiles\\"+File+"";
XSSFWorkbook hwb =new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("Data");
XSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("my");
XSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)i);
String value = "PrincipalOffice~DIRECTION";
row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(value);
FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
hwb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
hwb.close();
```

I have tried with 3.15 and 3.17 jars of apache poi
Do I need to use some other libary?, if yes please suggest

Comment: Can you try with Apache xmlbeans 3.0.1 and the release candidate of Apache POI 4.0?

Comment: Hi gagravarr -- thanks for your reply .. currently apache have 3.17 version latest .. refer : -https://poi.apache.org/download.html , I have also try to ass xml beans still getting same issue

Comment: That's the latest stable released one, yes. 4.0 is out for vote, so you can try the release candidate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `0x0F` or `&#15;`, you are mentioned, is not able to store directly in `XML` since it is a control character. So since `*.xlsx`  files stores content using `XML`, that character cannot be stored directly.

Nevertheless does Microsoft defining:
[ECMA-376 Part 1 22.4 Variant Types 22.4.2.4 bstr (Basic String)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm):

> 22.4.2.4 bstr (Basic String)
>
> This element defines a binary basic string variant type, which can store any valid Unicode character. Unicode characters that cannot be directly represented in XML as
>   defined by the XML 1.0 specification, shall be escaped using the
>   Unicode numerical character representation escape character format
>   `_xHHHH_`, where H represents a hexadecimal character in the character's value. [Example: The Unicode character 8 is not permitted in an XML
>   1.0 document, so it shall be escaped as `_x0008_`. end example] To store the literal form of an escape sequence, the initial underscore shall
>   itself be escaped (i.e. stored as `_x005F_`). [Example: The string
>   literal `_x0008_` would be stored as `_x005F_x0008_`. end example]
>
> The
>   possible values for this element are defined by the W3C XML Schema
>   string datatype.

This extends the W3C XML Schema string datatype. So that the character sequence `_xHHHH_` does have a special meaning as a kind of entity like `&#xHHHH;`.

So the following will work and `Excel` will have the character `0x0F` as cell content.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelControlCharacter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

  String value = "PrincipalOffice\u000FDIRECTION";

  value = value.replace("\u000F", "_x000F_");

  cell.setCellValue(value);

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelControlCharacter.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
 }

}
```

But may I ask why you are needing this control character to be a `Excel` cell content? That could be the answer to my question [Useful use cases for escape character format _xHHHH_ in Office Open XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315944/useful-use-cases-for-escape-character-format-xhhhh-in-office-open-xml).

Comment: Hey Axel ... I m out of office now .. will try tomorrow for sure ... Mean while can you please all guide me that if my this special character comes from an external source like DB then how to I replace it with it as Eclipse also do not accept that Unicode ... In that's case how I use replaceAll

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Axel point.

There are many control characters. To identify them dump your data to notepad++ or any tool which will show you the control character name/detail.

Below are the link which has listed all control characters

https://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm

Now found its unicode on google like "si unicode". you will found an string like U+000F.

Now replace the string as `\u000F` and put in replace like `_x000F_`

Some examples:

```
U+000F <Shift In> (SI) Unicode Character - Compart

value = value.replace("\u000F", "_x000F_");

U+001C <File Separator> (FS) Unicode Character - Compart

value = value.replace("\u001C", "_x001C_");

U+001E <Record Separator> (RS) Unicode Character - Compart

value = value.replace("\u001E", "_x001E_");
```