# How does Apache Poi set Workbook to make its cells not convert string such as “_x1128_” to Unicode

Tags: character-encoding, apache-poi, export-to-excel

if i just write string "_x1128" in a SXSSFCell,and then write it to a excel, it will change to "ᄨ",how to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like result of the `=UNICHAR(VALUE(HEX2DEC(1128)))` formula. The character is `ᄨ` (U+1128,  *Hangul Choseong Pieup-Chieuch*)… Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315944/useful-use-cases-for-escape-character-format-xhhhh-in-office-open-xml.